# RxJava Throttling Observables by Buffering and not Dropping

Tags: java, reactive-programming, rx-java

I feel like I have a relatively simple problem for the Reactive style of programming, but can't seem to get exactly what I want.

The problem: I need to hit an API that has rate limits and I need to adhere to the rate limits.

What I've looked at:

I've looked at all the different throttle methods to see if anyone of them would fit what I want, but noticed that throttle will throw away items coming down a stream. Instead I want something that just buffers things until I'm under the rate limit, and then continue.

I've looked at buffer, and it seems to be a good fit. The problem is that it will not really throttle the requests, only group them together by a certain amount of time.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: do you have your requests generated from a source `Observable`? how is it constructed?

Comment: What's your throttle requirements?

Comment: My requests are kicked off by an `Observable`. Simply put I have the following flow path. `Get IDs from DB` -> `Request Data` -> `Store in DB`. What I would like is something that mimics `Get IDs from DB` -> `Throttle/Buffer IDs coming from DB subject to rate limits` -> `Request Data` -> `Store in DB`. Basically I can only make a certain number of requests per 10 minutes, and per day.